# Никак не могу переписать код aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Уже много раз обращался к AI, всё равно не понимаю как исправить ошибки в этом коде.

У меня установлен aiogram 3.4.1

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

# Токен вашего бота
TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# ID вашего канала
group_id = ###

async def send_dice(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_dice(chat_id=group_id)

# Регистрируем обработчик для команды /cube
dp.register_message_handler(send_dice, commands=["cube"])

async def start():
    await dp.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())
```

Ошибка которая возникает:

```
File "c:\Users\progr\Desktop\Telegram_bot\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: попробуй обратиться не к AI, а к документации.

Comment: Сразу: dp.register_message_handler(send_dice, commands=["cube"]), эта история из aiogram 2

Answer (score 0):

Установите aiogram < 2.9. В aiogram 3.0 и выше существенные изменения по сравнению с прошлыми версиями.